# Angular JS Filter Reverse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-filters

Using this angular JS feature in angular is it possible to not display the results on page load?

But when a user types in the search box then the filtered results appear?

See link for the feature in using:

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

This appears to be what I'm after but I'd rather the results on page load didn't show.

Here's my code:

```
$scope.members = Members.query({key:$scope.Key}); //Grabs Json from API, can confirm results do come through.

        $scope.myFilter = function(obj) {
            if (!$scope.searchText)
              return false;
            else
              return obj.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        }
```

My HTML

```
<div class="list">
                        <div class="item">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
                        </div>  
                        <div ng-repeat="m in members | filter:myFilter" class="item item-button-right">
                            {{ m.first_name | limitTo: 1 }}{{m.first_name.length > 1 ? '. ' : ''}}{{m.last_name}}
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what is going to be in the search box before the user changes the content then you could hide the result element when it is matching that value. So you could do:

```
<div ng-hide="searchInput === 'my search'"></div>
```